# Blender crashes switching from curve editor to 3D view

Tags: animation

I've been using Blender for animation with png-based textures for a few years now and am pretty used to it crashing from memory overloads every now and again. However, I'm currently working on a project where after doing some path modifications in the graph editor, it will consistently crash whenever I try to switch back to 3D view.

I'm guessing viewing it in "material" mode is giving it some kind of memory overload when it tries to switch to 3D view but I don't know how to change the view settings outside 3D view, so I can't stop that from happening. Any idea how to change it remotely?

I'm running it on a newish Mac with OS 10.13.2 and the latest iteration of Blender.

EDIT: Fixed - Must've been a bug. After trying nearly everything I tried copying all the objects into a new file. Bulk-copying crashed it so I copied file by file, then groups of files by groups of files, until I found that one particular object was causing the crash when I tried to carry it over to the new file. I deleted it in the old file and it seems to work now.

It was weird because it was just a plane with a texture mapped on and there are literally hundreds of other planes with the exact same texture (lazy group scene - might've been a more efficient way to do it but this was what I came up with first).

Whatever the case, thank you for your answers!

Comment: If this is an error that happens constantly you should file a bug report. Please read: [Best place to put bug reports?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: Yes, you already seem to have made most of the legwork. If you could pinpoint the exact object be sure t pack all textures into the file then attach it to a bug report

Answer (score 0):

You could try limiting the texture size temporarily until you can get the issue worked out. This may help avoid large amounts of memory being reserved, and causing Blender to crash.

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> to open the **"User Preferences"**.

Switch to the **"System"** tab and change your *Texture Size Limit*.

[image]

This should limit the size of the textures, speeding up the viewport.

I recommend **NOT** clicking **"Save User Settings"** if you don't want this limit on your future Blend files.

Comment: This is an interesting idea which sadly didn't work in this case.